# Disabling Selection with CellList

Tags: java, gwt, celllist

I have a `CellList`:

```
friendCellList = new CellList<PlayerDataEntity>(new PlayerCell());
friendCellList.setSelectionModel(new NoSelectionModel<PlayerDataEntity>());
```

I am hoping that passing the `NoSelectionModel` will prevent the UI from reacting to the user selecting items in the cell list. However, the user is able to select elements normally. Am I not applying the selection model correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456273/disable-selection-for-gwt-celllist

Answer (score 3):

From the Javadoc of NoSelectionModel:

> A selection model that does not allow selection, but fires selection change
>    events. Use this model if you want to know when a user selects an item, but
>    do not want the view to update based on the selection.

That's what it does: In the Standard theme, this will result in the row not being highlighted in blue anymore ("cellListSelectedItem" style class). However, it will still be highlighted in yellow ("cellListKeyboardSelectedItem" style class). Also, the SelectionChangeEvent will still be fired.

To turn off the SelectionChangeEvent, use

```java
cellList.setSelectionModel(new NoSelectionModel<String>(), 
  DefaultSelectionEventManager.<PlayerDataEntity>createWhitelistManager());
```

The whitelist manager without arguments means, that you can't select any column.

If you also want to turn off the "yellow" highlighting, you should instantiate CellList with a different CellList.Resources instance:

```java
public interface MyResources extends CellList.Resources {
  @Override
  @Source("com/mypackage/my.css")
    Style cellListStyle();
}
...
friendCellList = new CellList<PlayerDataEntity>(new PlayerCell(),
    (MyResources) GWT.create(MyResources.class);
```

my.css:

```css
.cellListEvenItem {}
.cellListKeyboardSelectedItem {}
.cellListOddItem {}
.cellListSelectedItem {}
.cellListWidget {}
```

Comment: I still want selections to be displayed for a subset of items.

Comment: What would be the approach if I want some items to be selectable and some not to be selectable?